# Testing touchscreen with Android Emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, touchscreen

Is it possible to simulate or test Touchscreen input with the Android Emulator?

I'm working on a project which needs to support touchscreen input, but I don't have an Android phone myself. However if I could use my mouse to simulate/test touchscreen support in my app, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement the OnTouchListener and then on the emulator you can use your mouse.

A small tutorial here

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3279/android-the-basics-32-androids-ontouchlistener-and-motionevent/

Answer (score 1):

It's  theoreticaly possible.  But to date multitouch support requires a real Android 4.0 device to send multitouch input to the emulator. However, in this case you don't need the emulator and  can test directly on the physical device.

You can read latest information about multitouch support [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation).